# How to mach and get the value from dict n python?

Tags: python

```
dict ={"Rahul":"male",
       "sahana":"female"
       "pavan":"male" }
```

in a text file we have 
  rahul|sharma
  sahana|jacob
  Pavan|bhat

in a python program we have to open the text file and read the all line and "Name" we have to match with dict what we have and make a new text file with gender..

OUTPUT SHOULD BE LIKE
 rahul|sharma|male
 sahana|jacob|female
 Pavan|bhat|male

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: `dict[b.split('|')[0]]`?

Comment: It's kind of unclear what `b` is. Could you clarify? Is it a string, or are you using the `|` operator on two previously defined names? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that this is roughly what you want. Note that your formatting for input and output was slightly off, but I'm pretty sure I've got it.

```
genders = {"rahul":"male",
           "sahana":"female",
           "pavan":"male" }

with open("input.txt") as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        a, b = line.strip().split("|")
        gen = genders[a]
        print("{}|{}|{}".format(a, b, gen))
```

where `input.txt` contains

```
rahul|sharma
sahana|jacob
pavan|bhat
```

will correctly (I think) produce the output

```
rahul|sharma|male
sahana|jacob|female
pavan|bhat|male
```

I have changed all of your data to be lowercase, as with your casing, it would have been ambiguous as to how to lookup in the dictionary, and how to end up providing output (only one key was capital-cased, so I couldn't use any kind of reasonable string function to accomodate the keys as they were). I've also had to add a comma to your dictionary.

I've also renamed your dictionary - it's no longer `dict`, because `dict` is a Python builtin. It seems a bit strange to me that you will have available in your code a dictionary that can anticipate your input file, but this is what I got from the question.

Answer (score -1):

To get the value for the key in a dict, the syntax is simply:

```
b = "Rahul"
dict = {"Rahul":"male", "Mahima":"female"}
dict[b]
```

Comment: "b" will be in some .txt file and that have to match with this dict if name is there we have to add the gender and make one more text file ... pls help

Comment: Please update the question to include this information in a clear manner.